# How do I read a complex POJO from a flattened XML structure using Jackson?

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I have some in-memory data structures that I load from an XML file, and want to expose a simplified API without tying the XML or any users of the data structures to the implementation details.  I'm using Jackson for the XML unmarshalling.

### Data Structures

As you can see in the code, the `Profile` class contains an instance of `User`, but directly exposes the getters/setters for `User`'s fields.  I don't want to have a setUser(User)/getUser() because I want that implementation detail to be hidden from the public API.

**Profile.java:**

```
package com.example.data;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "profile")
public class Profile {
    private User user;
    private String email;

    @XmlElement(name = "userID")
    public String getUserID() {
        return user.getUserID();
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "userID")
    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        user.setUserID(userID);
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "password")
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "password")
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        user.setPassword(password);
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

**User.java:**

```
package com.example.data;

public class User {
    public String userID;
    public String password;

    public String getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

As you can see, I've tried adding @XmlElement JAXB annotations on the getters and setters without any success.  I also tried @JacksonXmlProperty but didn't have any luck with that, either.

### Data

I also don't want to have to wrap the `<userID>` and `<password>` in a `<user>` tag; I want the XMl to be flat as shown below.

**profile.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<profile>
    <userID>bob</userID>
    <password>letmein</password>
    <email>bob@example.com</email>
</profile>
```

### Application

**JacksonXMLExample.java:**

```
package com.example;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.example.data.Profile;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationModule;

public class JacksonXMLExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        File file = new File("src/main/resources/profile.xml");

        ObjectMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
        JaxbAnnotationModule module = new JaxbAnnotationModule();
        mapper.registerModule(module);
        Profile profile = mapper.readValue(file, Profile.class);

        System.out.println(profile);
    }

}
```

### Maven

**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>JacksonXMLExample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-xml-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

### The Problem

When I try executing the above code, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: N/A
 at [Source: src\main\resources\profile.xml; line: 3, column: 13] (through reference chain: com.example.data.Profile["userID"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:262)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty._throwAsIOE(SettableBeanProperty.java:537)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty._throwAsIOE(SettableBeanProperty.java:518)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:99)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:260)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:125)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3807)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2691)
    at com.example.JacksonXMLExample.main(JacksonXMLExample.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.data.Profile.setUserID(Profile.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:97)
    ... 5 more
```

How do I use a complex POJO composed of other POJOs without having to mirror that structure in the corresponding XML or expose implementation details to user of the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was ready to post my question, I had a facepalm moment when I realized that all I needed was to initialize the `user` field in Profile.java:

```
private User user = new User();
```

This is necessary because, of course, you cannot delegate method calls to a member that has not been initialized.